# Determine radius of a rounded rectangle

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, tools

I have a psd that has rounded rectangle. I need to create a new rounded rectangle with the same radius. How do I determine the radius used on that said rounded rectangle?

I feel like this is such an awful question but thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Just checking to see if my response answered your question?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65229/72184 The answer there is to select the vector object with the Path tool, and open the Properties panel, to view the radius:
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65245/72184 Another answer is to select the vector object with the Shape tool, and look at the options. Unfortunately, changing the options only works for creating a new object.
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38845/72184

Answer (score 6):

You can see the radius of a rounded rectangle by selecting the rectangle with the path selection tool (black arrow icon in the toolbar) and opening the properties panel. (see screenshot)

[image]

This will only work if the rectangle is still a vector shape and has not been rasterized.

Comment: I couldn't find properties on CS5, is there a way to see this window?

Answer (score 5):

Select your rectangle with the direct selection tool ([image]), so you can see the vector nodes. Then zoom in <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> until you can see the pixel grid.

Now you can count the number of pixel rows between the two nodes, this is the value you need to use for your new rounded rectangle radius.

In this example the radius is 10px.

[image]