# Adjust rounded rectangle radii without creating a new one in Photoshop C6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

When I create new rounded rectangles, I see the radii and other information in the properties, but after I work on something else and go back to that layer, the information does not show. How do I adjust the radii of the rounded rectangles without deleting and creating a new one?

Comment: If you've edited in a manner which has caused the properties to be expanded (thus removed) there is no way other than recreating the rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

After working elsewhere and when you come back to work on this layer, make sure 'shape tool' is selected, and you may have what you want in the top-bar.

[image]
[image]

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't edited the layer/shape yet just pick the `Path selection tool` and click on the shape. The `Properties panel` should now be active again.

[image]

Hope this helps.