# Photoshop - Is it possible to find the current border radius of a rounded rectangle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes

Here's the scenario: I create a rounded rectangle (shape layer) with a border radius of 8px (all sides). Months later I'm ready to code the design only to forget the border radius. Is there any way to rediscover these attributes (aside from properly naming the layer obviously)?